# Problem with code writing for unity and maybe inheritance in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity so I am a bit confused. I will be extremely glad if someone helps me with the problem I have. When I start to write my code in visual studio there are not any key worlds that appear when u start to write your code and also in the solution explorer there is a message: Assembly-CSharp.csproj:The application is not installed. I tried to switch to lower version of the Visual Studio Code Editor package to 1.1.3 and also I installed the nesesary Game development for Unity from the visual studio installer. I also have this problem and can not find what I miss. Please tell me if you have any idea, thank u in advance.

Comment: Found several suggestion when searching for "unity Assembly-CSharp.csproj:The application is not installed".

Comment: Are you talking about `Visual-Studio` or `Visual-Studio-Code`? Note that these are two completely different products! If it is `Visual-Studio` do you have the `Visual-Studio-Tools for Unity` installed via the `Visual-Studio Installer`?

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to Unity too. It will be simpler to use **Visual Studio** instead of **Visual Studio Code**. My suggestion is to install visual studio from **Unity Hub**. It will be very simple. I have added links that can help you. I hope I could help.

[image]

[Installing the Unity Hub](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GettingStartedInstallingHub.html)

[Visual Studio & Unity: Installation and Setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nna58aKumJ8)